# How to find the base of Hom(U, V)

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that Hom(U, V) is a vector space, which means it has a base.
What is the way to find the base of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have explicit bases $\{u_1,...,u_m\}$ of $U$ and $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ of $V$ you can construct a basis of ${\rm Hom}(U,V)$ as follows: let 
$$
\phi_{i,j}(u_k)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
v_j & \text{if $i=k$}\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
$$